# How to use weather fonts in iOS SDK

Tags: ios, fonts

I am developing for both android and iOS. I have an weather API in which I have to show a particular icon based on climate condition. I am using `Weather.ttf` fonts to do so.

In android I am doing like this :

```
    <string name="weather_sunny">&#xf00d;</string>
    <string name="weather_clear_night">&#xf02e;</string>
    <string name="weather_foggy">&#xf014;</string>
    <string name="weather_cloudy">&#xf013;</string>
```

And using the name I can get the Image.

But when In `iOS` I assign the text  `&#xf00d;` to `UILabel` I am getting this text as output. How can use this to get a Icon.

Comment: may this link will help you http://www.creativebloq.com/app-design/icon-fonts-in-apps-21410734

Comment: @muku  I tried this one also but unicode charaters work..but when it enter `&#xf00d;` it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally After Day of efforts I come to this solution.
To use weather fonts in `iOS SDK` you need Weather.ttf font file.

The code I was using to show Icons is `&#xf013;` which is `HTML Entity` thats why I was not able to render it.

So I use [this](http://www.endmemo.com/unicode/unicodeconverter.php) link to convert it in `UTF String` the I used that code.

Please make sure you are using correct font Name.To find Correct font name I use this code.

```
 NSArray * fontsArray = [UIFont familyNames];//this gives array of all fonts 
 NSArray *newArray = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"Weather Icons"];//Weather Ions must be listed in fontsArray so that you get all details in newArray
```

Now you have to just set the font and UTF code to UILabel

```
[lblCloud setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"WeatherIcons-Regular" size:14.0]];
lblCloud.text =  [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"\uf014"];
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to add your ttf to your project and, in your project.plist (Info.plist by default), you have to add an entry called "Fonts provided by application". Inside this entry, you have to add the name of your ttf files.

NOTE: This don't allow you to set this font on Interface Builder. You have to set it manually by code.
Example: [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"name_of_your_font" size:12.0]];

**UPDATE**

And then, try to set text with a stringWithUTF8String with "\xEF\x80\x8D".

**UPDATE 2**

The name of the font is "WeatherIcons-Regular". And according to the value, you have to set it as a simple string with '\u' before the value:

```
[label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"WeatherIcons-Regular" size:12.0]];
[label setText:@"\uF00D"];
```

And that's all. I've tested it and it works.

Comment: Oh, I haven't seen. That's just like it's explained in the link muku posted

Comment: I am not able to use that...  other codes are working but my weather.ttf is not working

Comment: Try with "\xEF\x80\x8D", that is the &#xf00d transformation to UTF-8 hex. I'm going to update my answer

Comment: I will let you know after trying this

Comment: I am geting a question mark in square box when I use  \xEF\x80\x8D with  UTF-8 hex

Comment: I think your problem is the name of the font. I'm going to update my answer

Comment: thanx @nigelman ... You answer helped very much.... But I am posting complete answer  please see....although yours is also best

Comment: What's the difference between your answer and my answer, that makes yours "the answer"? I don't understand...